# Función actualizadora no funciona en variable context api - react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, context

por favor su ayuda, estoy creando un sistema de encuestas. Cada encuestas tendrá un número no determinado de preguntas, por lo que el pintado de las mismas se realiza de manera dinámica, es decir, si es tipo select, text, numérico, etc... para cada uno renderizo un componente diferente.
Ahora, bien, he creado un RespuestasContext, un contexto para tener las respuestas de los diferentes módulos u/o encuestas de manera global, de tal manera que cuando abandone un módulo y posteriormente vuelva a regresar me cargue las respuestas que el usuario ya tenía diligenciadas.

En el contexto tengo el siguiente código:

```
import React from "react";

const RespuestasContext = React.createContext();

//Provider
const RespuestasProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [respuestas, setRespuestas] = React.useState({});

    const manejadorRespuestas = (modulo, codPregunta, respuesta) => {
        let tmp_respuestas = respuestas

        if (tmp_respuestas.hasOwnProperty(modulo)) {
            //Actualizar      
            if (tmp_respuestas[modulo].hasOwnProperty(codPregunta)) {
                tmp_respuestas[modulo][codPregunta] = {
                    respuesta
                }
            } else {
                insertar({ modulo, codPregunta, respuesta })
            }

        } else {
            //Insertar
            insertar({ modulo, codPregunta, respuesta })
        }
        setRespuestas(tmp_respuestas);

        return respuestas;
    }

    const insertar = (data) => {

        let tmp_respuestas = respuestas

        const { modulo, codPregunta, respuesta } = data

        if (tmp_respuestas.hasOwnProperty(modulo)) {
            tmp_respuestas[modulo][codPregunta] = {
                respuesta
            }
        } else {
            tmp_respuestas[modulo] = {
                [codPregunta]: {
                    respuesta
                }
            }
        }
        setRespuestas(tmp_respuestas);
    }

    const data = {
        respuestas,
        manejadorRespuestas     
    }

    return <RespuestasContext.Provider value={data}>{children}</RespuestasContext.Provider>;
}
export { RespuestasProvider };//themeProvider
export default RespuestasContext;//themecontext
```

En el componente donde pinto el formulario tengo algo como esto:

```
const { respuestas, manejadorRespuestas } = useContext(RespuestasContext);

    renderQuestions = ({ item, index }) => {

        if (item.TIPO_CONTROL == 'text') {

            manejadorRespuestas(item.ID_MODULO, item.CODIGO, '')
            console.log('ping => ',respuestas[item.ID_MODULO][item.CODIGO].respuesta)

            return (
                <InputText
                    label={item.DESCRIPCION}
                    value={respuestas[item.ID_MODULO][item.CODIGO].respuesta}
                    onChange={(value) => {
                        manejadorRespuestas(item.ID_MODULO, item.CODIGO, value)
                        console.log('respuestas ', respuestas)
                    }}
                />
            )
        }
}
```

Cada vez que cambia el value del input, la función actualizadora actualiza los valores en la variable respuestas del contexto, pero por alguna razón, cuando acceso a ella en el value, de esta forma : `value={respuestas[item.ID_MODULO][item.CODIGO].respuesta}` no se refleja el cambio, simplemente me borra nuevamente el campo, por lo tanto el valor en la variable del contexto siempre tiene una letra que es le primer caracter que digito en el input tal como se observa en la consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si quiero escribir "Barrio el prado" por ejemplo, al escribir la primera letra "B" se llama a la función actualizadora.. no sé que podría estar causando este problema.

El campo "NOMBRE DEL BARRIO O VEREDA" es el código de pregunta 556 como se ve en la consola.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Describe con mas detalle el comportamiento de ese input, un estado se utiliza como variable set por lo que si en el campo ya había entradas react lo muestra, si ya había entradas y lo quiero editar nuevamente, entonces coloco el cursor en el input, presiono una tecla y se borra todo e inicia de nuevo en vacío, eso es un comportamiento normal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo pude resolver de la siguiente manera, el contexto quedó con dos funciones principales, una función actualizadora, o manejadora de la respuesta, una función para obtener la respuesta:

```
import React from "react";

const RespuestasContext = React.createContext();

//Provider
const RespuestasProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [respuestas, setRespuestas] = React.useState({});

    const manejadorRespuestas = (modulo, codPregunta, respuesta) => {           

        if (respuestas.hasOwnProperty(modulo)) {
            //Actualizar      
            if (respuestas[modulo].hasOwnProperty(codPregunta)) {
                respuestas[modulo][codPregunta] = {
                    respuesta
                }
            } else {
                insertar({ modulo, codPregunta, respuesta })
            }

        } else {
            //Insertar
            insertar({ modulo, codPregunta, respuesta })
        }
        setRespuestas(respuestas);

        return respuestas;
    }

    const insertar = (data) => {

        let tmp_respuestas = respuestas

        const { modulo, codPregunta, respuesta } = data

        if (tmp_respuestas.hasOwnProperty(modulo)) {
            tmp_respuestas[modulo][codPregunta] = {
                respuesta
            }
        } else {
            tmp_respuestas[modulo] = {
                [codPregunta]: {
                    respuesta
                }
            }
        }
        setRespuestas(tmp_respuestas);
    }
    const obtenerRespuesta = (modulo, codPregunta) => {

        let respuesta = '';

        if (respuestas.hasOwnProperty(modulo)) {
            if (respuestas[modulo].hasOwnProperty(codPregunta)) {

                return respuestas[modulo][codPregunta].respuesta                
            } else {
                return respuesta
            }

        } else {
            return respuesta
        }

    }

    const data = {
        respuestas,
        manejadorRespuestas,
        obtenerRespuesta
    }

    return <RespuestasContext.Provider value={data}>{children}</RespuestasContext.Provider>;
}
export { RespuestasProvider };//themeProvider
export default RespuestasContext;//themecontext
```

En el TextInput tuve que cambiar de value a defaultValue:

```
<TextInput
                style={{ fontSize: 24 }}
                onChangeText={onChange}
                defaultValue={value}  
                placeholder={placeholder}                                             
            />
```

Y en el componente TextInput quedó así:

```
<InputText
                    label={`${item.DESCRIPCION} | ${item.CODIGO}`}
                    value={obtenerRespuesta(item.ID_MODULO, item.CODIGO)}                    
                    onChange={(value) => {                        
                        manejadorRespuestas(item.ID_MODULO, item.CODIGO, value) 
                    }}
                />
```